# Return type deduction for template in-class friend functions in clang

Tags: templates, g++, c++14, friend, clang++

So up front, what I'm trying to do is not an really intended use case for in-class friend definitions. But it does work under g++ and, best I can tell, is supposed to work according to C++14 specs.

For the purposes of discussion, clang is 5.0.0 and gcc is 7.2.0, although I've tested with other recent and HEAD versions and got identical results. Everything compiled with c++14 flag.

The minimal reproduction of case I'm interested in is bellow.

```
#include <iostream>

auto foo();

template <typename T>
class Foo
{
    friend auto foo()
    {
        return (T)3.14;
    }
};

template <typename T>
void bar(T){}

int main()
{
    bar(Foo<float>{});
    std::cout << foo() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Gcc behavior: Compiles and runs. Outputs: 3.14

Clang behavior: Refuses to compile. Error: conflicting types for 'foo'

That in itself seems completely wrong, but since auto doesn't give clang any problems when I take away templatization of Foo, I decided to try and give the foo function a dummy template.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename X = int>
auto foo();

template <typename T>
class Foo
{
    template <typename X>
    friend auto foo()
    {
        return (T)3.14;
    }
};

template <typename T>
void bar(T){}

int main()
{
    bar(Foo<float>{});
    std::cout << foo() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Gcc behavior: Compiles and runs. Outputs: 3.14

Clang behavior: Compiles and runs. Outputs: 3

And yes, when compiled with clang, type deduction of foo depends entirely on default template parameter in declaration, despite not appearing anywhere in the definition. o_O

Finally, I decided to try and fix this particular behavior by throwing in a using directive.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename X = int>
auto foo();

template <typename T>
class Foo
{
    using Type = T;
    template <typename X>
    friend auto foo()
    {
        return (Type)3.14;
    }
};

template <typename T>
void bar(T){}

int main()
{
    bar(Foo<float>{});
    std::cout << foo() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Gcc behavior: Compiles and runs. Outputs: 3.14

Clang behavior: Compiler crashes. Every version I've tried.

The crash is an obvious bug, but I'm more interested in the first two examples. Is this a bug in clang as well? Or is there some subtle reason for why this should be undefined behavior, and I'm just getting lucky with gcc? And more importantly, can anyone think of a workaround that would work on both gcc and clang? The thing I'm trying to do is detect the type with which Foo was instantiated, provided that it is unique, at compile time from outside of Foo.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm still not entirely sure why Clang behaves this way, I have found a workaround that does compile on both Clang and GCC. The later raises a warning, but it can either be suppressed, or slight variation of definitions can be introduced with ifdefs to make the code compile cleanly on both.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T = void>
class A
{
public:
    friend auto foo(A<T>);
};

template <typename T>
class Foo
{
    friend auto foo(A<void>)
    {
        return (T)3.14;
    }
};

template <typename T>
void bar(T){}

int main()
{
    bar(Foo<float>{});
    std::cout << foo(A{}) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This allows deduction of return type of foo() to be based on template parameter with which Foo was instantiated, even if they happen in different blocks of code, which is precisely what I was looking for.